# Push two symbols to stack at once in a push down automata

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

I am pretty new to PDAs and I was solving a problem which asked to design a PDA for the following: $a^n b^{2n}$.

The transitions on the PDAs I've encountered so far have pushed only one symbol onto the stack at any time. Can we push two symbols?
Eg: for every $a$ I encounter I push two symbols.  Thus, the transition will be:

$\Delta(q_0, a,0;000) \to \Delta(q_0)$ 

where "$a,0;000$" indicates pushing two zeroes onto stack for every $a$ that it encounters.

Comment: You can push a string $w \in \Gamma^*$, where $\Gamma$ is the stack alphabet

Comment: I think that, even if you could push only one symbol per transition, you could modify your PDA to push the first -> move to a new state -> push the second -> continue as usual. So, it does not really matter, if we only care about the languages.

Comment: The answer is: take a look at the definition of PDA introduced in class. There are several possible definitions, and only you know which definition is the one your professor prefers.

Comment: A third option is to use multiple stack symbols encoding different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some options (from comments):

- By some definition of PDA, you can push a string $w \in \Gamma^\ast$, where $\Gamma$ is the stack alphabet. <sub>(from [abc](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/4765/abc)'s [comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72300/push-two-symbols-to-stack-at-once-in-a-push-down-automata#comment154836_72300))</sub>
- Even if you could push only one symbol per transition, you could modify your PDA to push the first -> move to a new state -> push the second -> continue as usual. <sub>(from [chi](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/43599/chi)'s [comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72300/push-two-symbols-to-stack-at-once-in-a-push-down-automata#comment154838_72300))</sub>
- The third option is to use multiple stack symbols encoding different things. <sub>(from [Raphael](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/98/raphael)'s [comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72300/push-two-symbols-to-stack-at-once-in-a-push-down-automata#comment154858_72300))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Just push 2 *a* in the stack for each *a* you see on the input, then pop 1 *a* for each *b*.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question.  The question asks: "Can we push two symbols?  Eg: for every a I encounter I push two symbols." - in other words, the question already mentions that approach, and is asking whether that is actually valid.  So I don't see how this is addressing the question that was asked.

Answer (score -1):

Here, the number of $b$s is twice the number of $a$s, so we have to push the $a$s in stack first. Once we start encountering $b$s, we transition on the first $b$ (but put nothing on the stack, just move to next state). After reaching the second $b$, pop the top $a$ as we transition on that $b$.

$z(q_0,a,z_0)\to(q_0,az_0)$

$z(q_0,a,a)\to(q_0,aa)$

$z(q_0,b,a)\to(q_1,a)$

$z(q_1,b,a)\to(q_2,E)$

$z(q_2,b,a)\to(q_1,a)$

$z(q_2,E,z_0)\to(q_f,z0)$

Comment: How does this answer the question?